# Should we declare Generic.xaml in all xaml pages?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, generics, windows-phone

I have a question. I got every design templates in Generic.xaml which is in folder Themes. But i need to declare that resources in every page so that i can access those resources. Like this,

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/PhoneApp1;component/Themes/Generic.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

I am declaring this in all pages. Is there any other way to declare this only once and use in all pages?

Comment: You can declare in the App.Xaml and call it inside pages

Comment: Thats great. Thanks for the response.